# How to change text color of item on select2

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-blade, laravelcollective

I need change text color of item on select2, I try this:

```php
{!! FORM::label('IdOrigenRechazo', 'Origen de rechazo:') !!}
{!! FORM::select('IdOrigenRechazo',$origen->pluck('Descripcion','Id'),null,[
    'class'=>'select2_single form-control select-input',
    'placeholder'=>''
]) !!}
```

But, I don't know, how to change text color of item.

Note: Don't need background color.

Pls.

Answer (score 1):

The 4th parameter where you have an array of options, you can add a custom styling for your element, so if I understand your question right, you can do it like this:

```
{!! Form::select('IdOrigenRechazo',$origen->pluck('Descripcion','Id'),null,['class'=>'select2_single form-control select-input','placeholder'=>'', 'style' => 'color:red']) !!}
```

Notice the added `style` attribute in the options array. You can change the `red` for the color that you wish to use.

Comment: try `color: red !important;` instead maybe the select2 library overrides the default one.

Comment: It does not work, I think it's because it's a `Select2`

Comment: you can either replace it in the select2 css file that comes with the library, or add an `id` attribute which takes precedence and put a style in your own css file.